# Triggering test suites from web interface for multiples test projects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automated-tests, mstest, coded-ui-tests

My problem is, I have multiple test projects/suites which are build to test different applications. I need to trigger the tests from a web based application by choosing which suite to run - like a one click triggering. I need to know if I can use a test controller or **any other method** to trigger the test suites/projects from a web application  to execute the tests in a remote machine and give me the results.

I also heard that test agents and controllers can only work for one project collection and it cant share same physical space for another test project collection. Is there anyway to configure them for my problem statement.

OR

I have even explored the MSTest.exe and VSTest.Console.exe methods of triggering the test cases from the web page, it works fine in the local machine, but when I publish and host the website on IIS, it say **"To run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test agent to run as an interactive process. For more information, see "How to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests That Interact with the Desktop""**

I am stuck here and need some pointers on how to go about this.Any sort of help be really helpful and appreciable.

Comment: Have you read the *How To* it advised you to read?

Comment: sorry @iabbott i didn't get you !

Comment: the message you get when you publish it tells you to read a *How To*, did you read it?

Comment: yes @iabbott i did it. It did not help me much. I even tried to host without publishing also. It gives the same error i have mentioned. But is working fine in the local system.